# Wanting to check if the user name exists in the database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying for several hours to get a solution to check if a user name exists or not, but it keeps adding the same user name I add (without outputting errors that it exists).

My current function;

```
function mysqli_result($res, $row, $field=0) { 
    $res->data_seek($row); 
    $datarow = $res->fetch_array(); 
    return $datarow[$field]; 
} 

function name_exists($name){
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','database');
    $name = ($name);
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE name = '$name'");
    // Count the amount of rows where username = $unsername
    $check = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    return (mysqli_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true:false;
}
```

My full code for validating the username and other things is illustrated below;

```
//Validates Username
if(empty($error)) {
    if(name_exists($name)==true){
        $email_error = "Sorry, the username: $name is already Taken.";
        $error = true;    
    }
    if(empty($name)) {
        $error = true;
        $email_error = "You Forgot to Enter Your Username!";
    }
    if(!preg_match('/^\w{5,}$/', $name)){
        $error = true;
        $email_error= "Invalid Username format.";
        // valid username, alphanumeric & longer than or equals 5 chars
    }
}
if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $error = true;
    $email_error = "Please Enter Valid Email ID";

}
if(strlen($password) < 6) {
    $error = true;
    $password_error = "Password must be minimum of 6 characters";
}
if($password != $cpassword) {
    $error = true;
    $cpassword_error = "Password and Confirm Password doesn't match";
}
if (!$error)
{
    // prepare and bind
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name,email,password) VALUES (?, ?, md5(?))");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $name, $email, $password);
    //$stmt->execute();
    if( $stmt->execute() == true) {
        $successmsg = "Successfully Registered! <a href='login.php'>Click here to Login</a>";
    } else {
        $errormsg = "Error in registering...Please try again later!";
    }
}
```

}

DB structure

```
id(int8)
name(varchar 30)
email(varchar60)
password(varchar40)
```

Comment: why need to check in application side..? it is better to enforce it in db side too... using [unique index](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-indexes.htm). -- why i suggest this, since your application might check whether the user name exists at the same time.

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `== true`. Your function goes through a lot of trouble to return a boolean value, so just do `if (name_exists($name))` and be done with it.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords with a uselessly weak hash like SHA1 or MD5**.

Answer (score 0):

On first note , you can add unique identifier to the name column in the database to avoid duplicate insertions.

Secondly let the query be

```
SELECT COUNT(id) 
FROM users 
WHERE name = ' ".$name." ' ";
```

Inside the single quotes the variable `$name` is treated as string `$name` instead of being replaced with the value of `$name`

Comment: Using concatenation here is *bad*. Using placeholders, like the other queries do, is how to properly fix this.

Comment: Make username UNIQUE. Then run a simple INSERT. If the INSERT fails, you know that the username is used already.

Answer (score 0):

replaced:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE name = '$name'");
```

with:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name FROM users WHERE name = '$name'");
```

i tested, it worked for me